# When should I apply demorgans law in programming?

Tags: demorgans-law

I think any programmer who has taken an intro to programming class had to memorize DeMorgan's law.

In case you don't know what it is, here is the gist

!(A && B) = !A || !B
!(A || B) = !A && !B

I was under the assumption that if i had to memorize it, I would find it applicable in a programming situation.  But I haven't had to use it at all.

Is there any reason why I should use it in programming?  Does it make the program faster, or does it make conditions easier to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping code readable is a big reason, and I'm sure whoever works on your code after you will agree it's an important one. And you'll save a CPU cycle or two if you only invert (!) one value instead of two.

Another reason is to bypass short-circuiting. When many languages see `!A || !B` they stop evaluating if !A is true because it doesn't matter if !B is true or not. !A is enough for the OR to be true.

If A and B are functions instead of variables, and you want both to execute, you're gonna have a problem:

`if( !save_record() || !save_another_record() ) {
  echo 'Something bad happened';
}`

Demorgan's laws let you replace that OR with an AND. Both sides of the AND need to be evaluated to make sure it's true:

`if( !( save_record() && save_another_record() ) ) {
  echo 'Something bad happened';
}`

Comment: Oh.  bypassing short-circuted evaluation.  well.  I didn't see that.  That is pretty cool.  Thanks.

Comment: If you track in which cases those two functions are called, you will find that this transformation does **not** change the behaviour: in the first version, `save_another_record` is called IFF `save_record() == true`: if `save_record()` is true, then `!save_record()` is false, and we need to look at the right side of `||` to get the result; if `save_record()` is false, then `!save_record()` is true and we don't need to execute the RHS. Applying this to the second version, you'll find it does the same thing.